# Intellij Javascript multiline structural search and replace

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, replace, multiline, structural-search

In our project a lot of angular unit tests contain following syntax:

```
inject(['dependency1', 'dependency2', function(_dependency1_, _dependency2_) {
    dependency1 = _dependency1_;
    dependency2 = _dependency2_;
}]);
```

In tests the array which lists the dependencies with string values is obsolete, since this is only useful when using minification. So we issued a coding convention to change this syntax to:

```
inject(function(_dependency1_, _dependency2_) {
    dependency1 = _dependency1_;
    dependency2 = _dependency2_;
});
```

Now I've been replacing a couple of these in existing code when I came across them, but I've gotten really tired of doing this manually. So I'm trying to solve this in IntelliJ by using structural search and replace. This is my search template so far:

```
inject([$injection$, function($argument$) {
    $statement$;
}]);
```

with occurrences:

- $injection$: 1 to infinite
- $argument$: 1 to infinite
- $statement$: 1 to infinite

The replace template is defined as follows:

```
inject(function($argument$) {
    $statement$;
});
```

This does not work for the example I defined in the beginning however, it only matches and replaces correctly for a single line statement in the function body, so following example is replaced correctly:

```
inject(['dependency1', 'dependency2', function(_dependency1_, _dependency2_) {
    dependency1 = _dependency1_;
}]);
```

Am I missing something? When I check out the simple if-else example on the [Jetbrains website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html?origin=old_help) I get the feeling that this should work.

I have tried removing the semicolon behind the $statement$ variable, this didn't match multiple lines and resulted in the semicolons being removed after replacement. I've also tried applying a regex expressions to the $statement$ variable, but these didn't help either.

```
((.*)=(.*);\n)+
```

didn't match, probably because the semicolon is filtered out by the IntelliJ structural search before the actual regex matching is performed.

```
(.*)=(.*)
```

matched, but it replaced with the same behaviour as without the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching multiple statements with a variable in JavaScript is currently broken because of [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154183).

Comment: ah, thanks for the tip. You saved me from spending my whole sunday trying to get this to work :)

Comment: I can still reproduce the problem in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.5. I've requested to reopen the bug in YouTrack.